# TinyMCE drag and drop files or attach files to tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE4.2 in my application for text editor. But I need to drag and drop files(not image) inside the editor , How can I do that.

Is it possible or not?

Even If I go for buy It will work or not?

Can any one suggest on this.